# create new instance of abstract class

Tags: c#-4.0

I have abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseEntityDate<T> where T : class
    {
void ExecFunction ( T[] I )
{
}

}
```

next abstract class use this

```
public abstract class BaseBOList<T> : T where T : class
    {
public void SomeFunction ( T[] VarObj )
{
BaseEntityDate<T> ObjectData = Activator.CreateInstance<BaseEntityDate<T>>();

ObjectData.ExecFunction ( VarObj );

}
}

public class MyClass
{
}
```

And then create  inherit class

```
public class NyInhClass : BaseBOList<MyClass>
{
}


MyClass[] ArrayMyClass = new MyClass[]() { new MyClass() };

NyInhClass  TestOb = new NyInhClass ();

TestOb.SomeFunction ( ArrayMyClass );
```

Also next use example

```
public class MyClass2
    {
    }
```

And then create  inherit class

```
public class NyInhClass2 : BaseBOList<MyClass2>
{
}


MyClass2[] ArrayMyClass2 = new MyClass2[]() { new MyClass2() };

NyInhClas2s  TestOb = new NyInhClass2 ();

TestOb.SomeFunction ( ArrayMyClass2 );
```

and so on

Accuared exception "CANNOT CREATE ABSTRACT CLASS"

Can Help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
object ExecuteBaseEntityDate ( T _Var )
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
}
```

In this example we are using the `Activator.CreateInstance` overload which is not generic but takes the type parameter dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'Eval3_DAL.EvaluationType' to type 'Eval3_DAL.BaseEntityDate`1[Eval3_DAL.EvaluationType]'.

Comment: Yes I want create this class at run time

Comment: Did you make the `MyTest` class to inherit from `BaseEntityDate<T>` as explained in my answer?

Comment: Yes I create but I want create uncial function for any class

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what `uncial function` means and what you are trying to achieve. If you want this to work you will have to make the `MyClass` inherit from the abstract `BaseEntityDate<T>` class.

Comment: public abstract class BaseEntityDate<T> where T : class
    {

Comment: In this case you may try directly returning the result of the `Activator.CreateInstance` call. I have updated my answer.

Comment: public abstract class BaseEntityDate<T> where T : class
        {
    void ExecFunction ( T[] I )
    {
    }
    
    }
and so on